# Are there restrictions in public transport during Semana Santa in Spain?

Tags: public-transport, spain, public-holidays

I'm currently traveling in Spain on public transport. With the Easter week (Semana Santa) coming up, do I have to expect limited services on long distance buses and trains? What about local transport in the cities? Finally do the ferries to Morocco run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the March 29th and the April 1st are bank holidays in Spain. Between them there is a weekend that may be affected. Also the March 28th is bank holiday in some regions.

There are not less transports in buses and trains, really there are more than a normal day, but there is more people trying to take it. In my experience, you should book your long distance transport one week before or you will have problems these days (and maybe the 3-4 days previous and the 3-4 days next). Anyway, Andalucia will be the most affected region.

About the Morocco ferries, the same applies. You can check the timetables and [book your passage here](http://www.aferry.co.uk/).

Answer (score 1):

In Barcelona there's not restrictions, just a lot of people. Anyway I recommend you, take the metro for moving on the city, neither taxi or car.

**EDIT:**

You can see the state of the metro and bus service for Barcelona city in the TMB's official web page.

http://www.tmb.cat/en/home

About the long distance trains, you can take a look at renfe's web page. It's valid for all the cities in Spain. You will find out information about services, trains and last hour news:

http://www.renfe.com/EN/viajeros/index.html

Hope it helps.